# ASP .NET MVC 3 DropDownListFor problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

In the Model, I have:

```
public Guid? Country
{ get; set; }
```

In the View, I have:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Country, (SelectList)ViewBag.Countries)
```

When submitting, error occures, cause it wants to save the string to the Guid. How to save the value rather then the text of the drop down list?

Comment: As a work-around you could add a `CountryString` property that wraps the GUID and set up your `DropDownListFor` to use that, but there must be a better way.

Comment: Ok. I've changed my code a little and this is what I'm using in the view: @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Country, new SelectList(ViewBag.Countries, "ID_Country", "ISO_Code"), ""); basically, I've just moved the SelectList() constructor call from controller to the view. And this is how I get countries to the ViewBag from the Controller (via Entity Framework): ViewBag.Countries = from e in new FarmerEntities().Countries select e;. Now I get the "Value cannot be null" exception (if I choose something or not). Please help!

Comment: From the looks of it, you are using ISO country codes (which are not GUIDs).  Is there a reason your data type for the country is a Guid instead of a string?

Comment: No. "ID_Country" is for DropDownLists' "hidden" value list and "ISO_Code" is for DropDownLists' "front"/visible value list. Everything works fine until submit.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. Got it working with a little bit of a different approach.

Model:

```
public UserRegistrationModel()
{
    this.InitializeCountries();
}

private void InitializeCountries()
{
    FarmerEntities fe = new FarmerEntities();
    var query = from c in new FarmerEntities().Countries select new { ID = c.ID_Country, Name = c.ISO_Code };
    var countries = query.ToSelectList(c => c.ID.ToString(), c => c.Name);

    this.Countries = countries;
}

public Guid? { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Countries
{ get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
UserRegistrationModel model = new UserRegistrationModel();

return View(model);
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Country, Model.Countries, "")
```

Also, you need to implement this extension

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectList<TItem, TValue>(this IEnumerable<TItem> items, Func<TItem, TValue> valueSelector, Func<TItem, string> nameSelector)
    {
        return items.ToSelectList(valueSelector, nameSelector, x => false);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectList<TItem, TValue>(this IEnumerable<TItem> items, Func<TItem, TValue> valueSelector, Func<TItem, string> nameSelector, IEnumerable<TValue> selectedItems)
    {
        return items.ToSelectList(valueSelector, nameSelector, x => selectedItems != null && selectedItems.Contains(valueSelector(x)));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectList<TItem, TValue>(this IEnumerable<TItem> items, Func<TItem, TValue> valueSelector, Func<TItem, string> nameSelector, Func<TItem, bool> selectedValueSelector)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var value = valueSelector(item);

            yield return new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = nameSelector(item),
                Value = value.ToString(),
                Selected = selectedValueSelector(item)
            };
        }
    }
}
```